# Load data to remote DB using sqlldr

Tags: oracle

I wanted to load data to remote db using sqlldr.I did it using following command

```
>sqlldr GANUKA/GANUKA@jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.21.0.180:1521:orcl control=D:\Work\CLSTMAS.ctl 
log=D:\Work\CLSTMAS.log
```

But it gives the following error.

```
SQL*Loader-704: Internal error: ulconnect: OCIServerAttach [0]
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Need a help

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You're mixing up two different worlds here. One is the OCI world where *sqlldr* lives. It expects Oracle instance names defined in TNSNAMES.ORA (or a similar service). The other world is the JDBC world that uses connection identifiers with words like "jdbc" or "thin".

So you have two options:

- If your environment has a proper TNS setup, you have to change the command line to something like `sqlldr GANUKA/GANUKA@MONTY.CORP control=...`
- If not, you can use an Easy Connect string: `sqlldr GANUKA/GANUKA@//172.21.0.180:1521/orcl control=...`

Comment: Your 2nd suggestion doesn't work for me and I'm not sure why. I get the following:

```SQL*Loader-704: Internal error: ulconnect: OCIServerAttach [0]
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor```

I tried with both ip address and hostname.

Comment: How do I provide the @... part when I want to prompt for username and password?

Answer (score 3):

I ended up having to use a thin client connection string. I couldn't get @Codo 's solution to work.

`sqlldr \'username/passwd@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost.com)(PORT=1111)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MYSIDE)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))\' control=loader.ctl data=data.csv`